# ng-model value is not updated out of the directive

Tags: angularjs

Please check Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zQfJtv7Q5sBQvyLE1RhK?p=preview).

The directive is loaded in a view as below

```
<logic-tree ng-model="myData"> </logic-tree>
```

And within the controller which loads the directive, the model is binded to a variable as below.

```
$scope.myData= { ... };

$scope.$watch( 'myData', function(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log("This is never called");
});
```

**When `updateModel` is called, `myData` is not updated.**

Please anyone knows where the problem is.

Comment: Try changing your isolated scope to `ngModel : "="` in your directive. The `&` is mostly used for passing functions.

Comment: @AhmedWagdi I tried `=`,  still not working. I updated the question with `=` now

Comment: a plunkr would be helpful, i tried this in a simple example and the $watch works so a live example would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updateModel function should have $render also:

```
 updateModel = function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($scope.source);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          });
        }, 0);
      };
```

Comment: I tried and It does not work.  And as I understand `$render` is to update the view.  What I want is to trigger the listener `$scope.$watch( 'myData' )`

Comment: can you create plnkr ?

Comment: also did you try deep watching?
$scope.$watch( 'myData', function(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log("This is never called");
},true);