# Angular ngModel with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass down an object into a directive that can then update this value. so far i have the following:

```
 <competence-select ng-model="module.selectedCompetence"></competence-select>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('Competence').directive("competenceSelect", ['competenceService', function (competenceService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/Competence/directives/competence-select/competence-select.html',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue = scope.competenceList;
            scope.competences = [];


   competenceService.getCompetenceList().then(function (result) {
                scope.competences = result;
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

(Notice the require)

And then my directive html:

```
    <label translate="FORMS.COMPETENCES"></label>
<ui-select multiple reset-search-input="true" ng-model="competenceList" theme="bootstrap"
           ng-disabled="disabled">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{ 'FORMS.COMPETENCES_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}">{{$item.name}}
        &lt;{{$item.competence_type_id == 1 ? 'Faglig' : 'Personlig' }}&gt;</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices group-by="someGroupFn"
                       repeat="competence in competences | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, competence_type_id: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="competence.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small>
            {{competence.name}}
            {{ 'COMPETENCES.TYPE' | translate:{TYPE: competence.competence_type_id} }}
        </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Now what i want to do is fairly simple:

```
ngModel$setViewValue = scope.competence;
```

Setting this should set the `ng-model` in the view to be the ng-model i set on the directive. Thereby parsing the variable "up" to the declarating of the directive:

```
<competence-select ng-model="module.selectedCompetence"></competence-select>
```

Sadly this is not the case.

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Comment: Apparently you need to call `.$render()` to update the model as well and not just the view. Just googled it and found that https://jmcunningham.net/2014/08/09/angularjs-using-setviewvalue-and-render-to-update-models-forms/

Comment: @floribon its right we need to call .$render(). [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36858336/1147542)

Comment: `$setViewValue` is a function.

Comment: @Maverick good to know. Feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in your directive

```
angular.module('Competence').directive("competenceSelect", ['competenceService', function (competenceService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/Competence/directives/competence-select/competence-select.html',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope:{ ngModel : "=" }, 
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue = scope.competenceList;
            scope.competences = [];


   competenceService.getCompetenceList().then(function (result) {
                scope.competences = result;
                scope.ngModel = scope.competences;
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```